# Spring MVC 4 File Upload Failing Silently

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, file-upload, web-applications, tomcat8

I'm using Spring MVC (Version 4.1) on Tomcat 8, and am desperately trying to make the file upload functionality work. Currently, I have a controller configured like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/TestCase/Upload"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
     System.out.println("Hit this location.");
     return new ResponseEntity("Success");
}
```

My web.xml has the appropriate server configuration:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <!-- Configuration for file upload (configuring Multipart file) -->
    <multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp</location>
        <max-file-size>500000</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>505000</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>10485</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

And finally, my Spring xml configuration file has the necessary resolver specified:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="500000" />
    </bean>
```

The Apache commons-fileupload JAR is on the classpath.

I have used this approach successfully in the past on non-Tomcat servers, but now the application isn't working - but it's failing quietly. The response has a status code of 200, but nothing inside of the file upload controller method is executed. There are no exceptions thrown in the server logs, and the only way I can get the controller method to print anything out is if I remove the "Multipart" parameter entirely. At first I thought that the controller method wasn't being hit at all, but if I change the URL mapping, then the calling code throws a 404 - so it is definitely hitting the correct mapping/method - it's just that nothing inside of the method is executing (with *no* exceptions thrown!)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Spring MVC will hide noClassDef's from the console when booting itself up. The issue was that *apache-commons-io.jar* was missing on the classpath. Including that JAR caused everything to work properly.

So in the future if Spring is quietly misbehaving - check to ensure all necessary libraries are explicitly included, because it certainly won't tell you!